# Using Launch4j, when should I Wrap the Jar?

Tags: java, jar, launch4j

I'm new to Launch4j. By default, it "wraps" the jar, but there is a checkbox that reads "Dont't wrap the jar, launch only".

When should I check this box? When should I not check this box?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only difference is that when you check this option, the jar file is not packaged inside the generated executable file, and it needs the jar file next to it.

So you should not check the box if you want to hide the jar to your users and have a single executable file, and you should check it if you are willing to keep the executable file and the jar file separated (if you want to update the jar file without re-generating the executable for instance).